# I am the first if you see

Tags: riddle

I'm the first if you see, 3-in-one if you know, and soon to be three if you observe. What am I?

Comment: Consider reopening the question. I think it's pretty clear now with punctuation (doesn't mean I know the answer though).

Comment: Reopened, as the original close reason has been addressed. I suspect this question may be close-worthy on other grounds, in particular as it "may invite speculative answers, as the question is not fully defined. The validity of some answers may be based upon opinion. Good questions for this site have a limited number of objectively correct answers."  I'll leave that to the community to decide, as answers emerge.

Answer (score 9):

> Traffic lights.

Reasoning:

> If you just look, you see only one light. If you know what traffic lights are, you know there are three lights. And if you observe a set of traffic lights, you see the lights cycle through all three colours.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the

> Subject- object - verb trio of a sentence in English (or any language)

As,

> I'm (or any word of a normal sentence) is the subject - obviously. And then followed by verb (usually) and then an object. But, in this case they are reversed -  a thing *you know* becomes a subject(3 in one) and once you observe, it is the action/ verb you are talking about.

So,

> It is a specially constructed English sentence, without violating rules of grammar.

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> **Solar Eclipse**

Reasoning-

> *I'm the first if you see,*
>  **You see the Sun**
>  
>  
>  *3-in-one if you know,*
>  **As observed from the Earth, a solar eclipse occurs when the Moon passes in front of the Sun.** 
>  
>
>  *and soon to be three if you observe.*
>  **This occurs when the Sun, Moon and Earth are aligned.**

Answer (score 0):

It might be

> The Play/Pause/Restart Button on youtube (or other devices/applications).

At first glance

> When you choose a video, you have to click the play button to start.
>  [image]

After that, you observe

> And it turns into the pause button.
>  [image]

And at the end,

> It turns into the repeat button. But if you're a frequent user of Youtube, then you already know this.
>  [image]